# ubuntu slows down when connected via wifi

Tags: wireless, network-manager

I have a fresh ubuntu install and everything goes well when connected via ethernet cable. However, if I am to connect via wifi, ubuntu is not as smooth as it is with cable. It's not something crucial, as I can still work on it, but for instance, as I am writting this, it freezes for about half a second, and then it catches up to speed. So I type "writting", freezes just after the "w", and then the next frame "writting" is on the screen. This happens every 2-3 seconds.

Some additional information about the wifi adapter, it's a pci wifi card. This happens both on 5G and 2.4G bandwidths:

```
lspci | grep -i net
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
05:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8812AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, 18.04